# Как сохраняются данные об электронной почте и пароле в firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

допустим в приложении реализован вход по эл.почте и паролю, а также регистрация новых пользователей. Регистрируем новых пользователей с помощью createUserWithEmailAndPassword  который исходя из наших данных создаёт новою запись в бд firebase. Мне интересно в каком формате он их сохраняет. Могу ли я как разработчик или администратор просматривать и изменять эл.почту и пароль? В firebase бд я вижу только зашифрованный ключ. Если кто то использует это в своих приложениях, можете поделится информацией об этом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы авторизовались на сайте `Firebase`, слева у вас будет список `Develop`, в который входят `Авторизация, База данных, Библиотека, Хостинг, Функции и ML Kit`. Вам нужно перейти по пункту `"авторизация"`, у вас отобразится список людей, которые зарегистрировались в вашем приложении. Изменять почту или пароль человека вы не можете. В ваши возможности входят : *Сброс пароля*, *отключение аккаунта и удаление аккаунта*.